# Is Robocop's HUD built into his helmet?

Tags: robocop, robocop-1987

In the 1987 Robocop movies we can see how Robocop see details about people and is able to track targets.

**Is this (Heads-up) Display part of his helmet or is this how Robocop see things with his brain and eyes?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the final scene of the movie, he's walking around without the visor, and yet the HUD messages (Directive 4) are still visible (starts around 1:17)

Comment: Very Good point

Comment: Interesting. So perhaps it's only the targeting grid.

Answer (score 4):

Robocop's vision (without his visor) appears to be digital, but blurry and without the tracking overlay that we tend to think of as his normal vision. As you can see from the scene below, they mount an LED screen directly over his face (the visor) and then screw it down so that it's basically flush with his eyes. This screen seems to incorporate his tracking systems, an internal video screen and various audio-sensors.

He does seem to be able to use a zoom function with just his bare eyes.

As Machavity has pointed out in his answer, the "directives" seem to be [hardwired into his normal vision](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=126&v=QvmFhcGCRzA).